# Useragent showing 302 in code on browser it gives result

Tags: python, sockets, user-agent

I am trying to get some page result for search on google. My target is to get AMP results in the page. I tried Android kitkat user-agent  in my browser it results in listing amp pages in search result. But I am trying to search for the same keyword with same user agent using socket methods in python it gives 302 status code. [image]

```
user-agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; Nexus 4 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.114 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

if you carefully see bottom of the page its shows an amp page result for axisbank and you can see the user agent. But when i try to replace my  code user agent with the same it gives me 302. If i use another useragent  then results are listed but not amp pages.

```
        self.opened_url = self.buildUrl()
        print self.opened_url
        html=""
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) 
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25 , "eth0")
        s.connect((self.domain, 80))
        request = b"GET " +self.opened_url +" HTTP/1.1\nHost: " + self.domain + "\nUser-Agent:" + useragent + "\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\nConnection: close \nAccept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\n\n"
        try:
            s.send(request)
            content=""
            while (True):
                result = s.recv(1024)
                if len(result) == 0 :
                    break
                content = content + result
            s.close()            
            data = content.split('\r\n\r\n')
            code = int(data[0][9:12])
            print code
            if code == 301 or code == 302 or code == 403 or code == 503:
                    print "Captcha found"
                    print "content"
                    print content
                    self.has_captcha = True
                    return ""
```

This code works and gives result with another use agents  but does not list amp results. I want to get amp page in search results. Thanks for any help

Comment: 302 means the URL is valid, but the agent should be directed. The new url is available in the header of the response.  So either deal with that in your code; or use a library that will handle all this for you.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, Yes the new url is in the apge dump but as per my requirement i have to open the exact page (self_opened_url) otherwise google will give some other results that may not be organic results for the keyword searched. so redirecting to that page or opening a new url is not an option for me

Comment: You are not the one redirecting, Google is. So I am not sure what result - other than the 302 - do you wish to record for that URL.